# Android SocketServer crashing app

Tags: android, sockets

I've been trying to get a SocketServer working on my phone. I've recently upgraded to ICS so now I need to do my network stuff in a seperate thread, which I am not used to. I've written some code but as soon as I try to connect to the socket, the app crashes.

I start the serverSocket when a toggle on-off switch is switched:

```
final Switch connectionSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.connectionSwitch);
connectionSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked) {
        new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    outToServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                while(connectionSwitch.isChecked()) {

                    myPacket[0] = (byte) 0xAA;
                    myPacket[1] = (byte) 0x01;
                    myPacket[2] = (byte) (fanFrontSpeed/256);
                    myPacket[3] = (byte) (fanFrontSpeed%256);
                    myPacket[4] = (byte) (fanLeftSpeed/256);
                    myPacket[5] = (byte) (fanLeftSpeed%256);
                    myPacket[6] = (byte) (fanRightSpeed/256);
                    myPacket[7] = (byte) (fanRightSpeed%256);

                    try {
                        outToServer.write(myPacket,0,8);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
});
```

The errors I get are:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4487
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Can you get the more specific error text via logcat? Otherwise we can only guess what may be null..

Comment: I've been messing around with it a bit more and have worked out the problem is with outToServer.write(myPacket,0,8). Either I am not using it correctly (I had previously been using writeInt which was working) or the way I am constructing myPacket is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to debug something like this is going step by step on the debugger and before executing each line check if anything is null.

e.g. of what might be happening:
during the server initialization, some error occurs, it is caught in UnknownHostException or IOException, now your code carries one with outToServer==null because it was never initialized, and whenver it tries `outToServer.write(myPacket,0,8);` you have a null pointer exception.

But it might be a billion of different things, that's just the most obvious I could think.